# How to add a new line with empty value in a table of Angular which used primeNG and the table shows the data of a database

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I'm using primeNG table in an Angular application. The table shows the data from a database. There are 'add' and 'delete' buttons.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U2bH.png
When I press the add button, a new line comes out in the bottom of the table but its empty. When filled in the required cells, you can save it so it will added to the database.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX1n9.png
So I wanna know how can I add a new empty line in the bottom of the table, it looks  like the empty value just saved in the session, onlu when required cells are filled in,you can save it to the database

Answer (score 0):

please could you provide some code in order to have a  ample view of the problem

Comment: This is not a code issue, I just want a method on how can I achieve what I wanted, there are 2 pictures in my question, maybe you'll understand what I said after you checked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for crud operation in PrimeNG site.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/crud

It has example of adding rows in table.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I don't need a dialog when add a new item. I just wish a new empty line showed up in the bottom of the table when I press the add button. And there're two pictures in my question, I wish you could check, thanks